# Comparing text fields to database data one by one

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I have many text fields that serve as the locker number and I want to check one-by-one if they are equal to the retrieved data. How is that possible to check them one-by-one?

```
try{
    String get = "SELECT no from accounts";
    rs = st.executeQuery(get);
    while(rs.next()){
        num = rs.getString("no");
        //System.out.println(num + " ");
    }
    if(s2149.getText().equals(num)){
        s2149.setBackground(Color.red);
    }             
    if(!s2149.getText().equals(num)){
        s2149.setBackground(Color.green);
    }
}catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());};        
}
```

Comment: How does the code you pasted relate to your question exactly?

Comment: i tried to use if statement. but it checks only one condition

Comment: Your problem is very vague. Please explain more in detail clearly

Comment: I really do't know how to explain this one. :((

Comment: ok, please explain what do you want to accomplish with your text background?

Comment: I have a locker numbers from 2149 - 2217. I create a text fields to set the numbers. now, if the user wants to rent it, it will be saved in db. my problem is, if the number is rented, the textfield's color will turn to red, if not. it will be back at green

Comment: also, how can I check weather it is rented or not?

Answer (score 0):

put the values of your inputs into a array, then in the loop have a counter (index), compare the current db value to the array.